# A+B Problem $o(n^2)$ solution?

Tags: algorithms, combinatorics

Does [this problem](https://open.kattis.com/problems/aplusb) have a solution with $o(n^2)$ time complexity?  If so, what would be an example of such a solution?

> Given $N$ integers in the range $[−50\ 000,\ 50\ 000]$, how many
>   ways are there to pick three integers $a_i$, $a_j$, $a_k$, such that $i$,
>   $j$, $k$ are pairwise distinct and $a_i + a_j = a_k$? Two ways are
>   different if their ordered triples $(i,j,k)$ of indices are
>   different.

I have come up with a $\theta(n^2)$ solution, but it exceeds the specified time limit for the ninth test.  I believe I could parallelize my $\theta(n^2)$ solution using multi-threading, but that is generally not in the spirit of the problems on this website.  That is what makes me think there is a $o(n^2)$ solution.  However, I have not been able to come up with a faster solution myself using either divide-and-conquer or dynamic programming.

Comment: For unbounded integers, this is the 3SUM problem, and it is conjecture that there is no $O(n^{2-\epsilon})$ solution for any $\epsilon > 0$. There are $o(n^2)$ solutions, but they're not practical.

Comment: See [the sentence just above the table-of-contents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3SUM). ​ ​

Comment: Thanks.  As a student, I'm finding that simply being able to name the problem is critical to researching more information about it...